# How to resolve 'failoverclusters' was not loaded PowerShell script error

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am trying to run the Batch file which runs the SSIS package. The SSIS package call the PowerShell script to fetch the data from different servers.  I am able to get the SSIS package working without any error. But whenever I try to run the batch file which calls the SSIS package, it fails with below error:

```
 import-module : The specified module 'failoverclusters' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any 
module directory.
At E:\XYZ\SSISPckg\Hypv\BASE\XYZ70GTNPENG003.ps1:6 char:1
+ import-module failoverclusters
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (failoverclusters:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
The term 'Get-ClusterGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
no vms in XYZ70GTNPENG003
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 15.0.4223.1 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
```

I did not get such error when I executed the PowerShell script from SSIS.

I was able to identify FailoverClusters module in powershell folder. I was able to locate it by running **Get-Module -ListAvailable** command.

I have already executed **Install-WindowsFeature "RSAT-Clustering-Powershell"** to install the required module. Except this module, I was able to import the other **Hyper-V** module.

So, can someone please help with understanding where I am making mistake. I am able to run the SSIS package which calls the powershell script using Execute Process Task. But if I call the batch file which run the SSIS package, it fails with above error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `FailoverClusters` module is only available from the x64 bit version of PowerShell. e.g. when you are opening PowerShell by yourself, it by default, opens the x64 bit version of PowerShell, and hence, is why your testing works. A 32 bit x86 version of the `FailoverClusters` module does not exist, and can't be run from a 32 bit environment.

You can see this is the case when you launch `Windows PowerShell (x86)` and try to load the module:

```
PS C:\> Import-Module failoverclusters
Import-Module : The specified module 'failoverclusters' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module failoverclusters
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (failoverclusters:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

When running SSIS packages from a `.bat` file, it defaults to the x86 version, which will launch the 32-bit x86 version of PowerShell, and hence, will throw the error message.

What you have to do is in your `.bat` file, explicitly launch the SSIS package with the x64 version of `DTExec.exe` something like this:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /FILE MyFile.dtsx
```

This will launch the x64 bit version of `DTExec.exe` which will in turn launch the x64 version of PowerShell, and make the `FailoverClusters` module available.